# Why doesn't std::swap work on std::aligned_union

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code doesn't quite work.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t Len, class... Types>
using dataType = typename std::aligned_union<Len,Types...>::type;

int main()
{
    dataType<1,int,float,std::string,char,bool> x;
    dataType<1,int,float,std::string,char,bool> y;

    new (&x) std::string("chicken");
    new (&y) std::string("boiled");

    std::swap(x,y);

    std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(&x) << " " << *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(&y) << std::endl;
}
```

for example, it prints `chicke boiled` without the `n`. It also hasn't swapped `x` and `y`, else it would print `boiled chicken`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://ideone.com/A3E0bL

Comment: That swap is swapping raw bytes. If the type isn't trivially copyable, that doesn't result in living objects, and any subsequent attempt to use it is UB.

Comment: @BlitzRakete The exact details of the implementation of `std::string` will determine what behavior you happen to get. Terrible, terrible things would happen if you tried this with a type derived from `shared_from_this`!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz oh I see thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't possibly work. The correct behavior of the swap would require knowing which type the union contains. This is not a discriminated union, so any operation that relies on knowing which type the union contains will fail unless specifically provided that information.

I'd love to hear how you imagine this could work, even conceivably. What magic do you think `std::swap` could possibly do?

Comment: fair enough, I should probably have read up about it. However, if I remove the std::swap and replace it with a temp to swap the values, I get the same result

Comment: @NeomerArcana And for the same reason. How could it conceivably work? How do you know what needs to be done to swap the values if you don't know what type the union is holding?

Comment: But it's not a union? It's a type that is capable of holding all of those types. Because it consists only of bytes, can't it just assign them? How would I achieve what I'm trying to do (might help me understand why this doesn't work)?

Comment: @NeomerArcana Suppose, for example, one of those types always holds a pointer to itself in the first few bytes. And say the other holds an integer value in those same few bytes. How could swap possibly work? Does it change the value to point to the new address or not? I honestly cannot understand how you could possibly imagine this could even conceivably work -- it's a non-starter.

Comment: Or say one of the values the union could hold registers a pointer to itself in a global collection and another of the values doesn't. Do you update the global collection or not? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: thanks. How would I go about copying the values from one aligned_union type to another of the same type? Say I tag it somehow to know the type it holds, would I just reinterpret_cast the aligned_union to the type I want and pass it to the types constructor? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @NeomerArcana You're going to need an algorithm that handles all the possible cases. If neither is seated, then it's a no-op. If one is seated, move its object to the other. If both are seated and they are the same type, swap the objects. If both are seated and they are different types, you will need a temporary.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ...and that point we are just reinventing `variant` :)

Comment: Yes. https://gist.github.com/tibordp/6909880 hence my initial confusion with aligned_union and swap (look at the assignment operator)

Comment: @T.C. Exactly. If you want a union that knows what type it contains and can be smart about that, you know where to find it.